# java(jsp) code similar to Convert.ToInt32(dropdownlist1.selectedItem)

Tags: java, jsp

What is the code similar to `Convert.ToInt32(dropdownlist1.selectedItem)` in java
and I also want to get the id (coming from back end -sql) of corresponding value selected from dropdownlist value(for example I have course `dropdown`, On selecting that course that time I want to get the corresponding integer id from sql server)

Answer (score 0):

Integer.parseInt converts a string to an int (32 bits)